# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages' Asp.Net Webforms Navigation

Tags: asp.net, webforms, navigation

I recently installed the package [Navigation] to an ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application. While I am running it on my local machine [I have VS 2012 installed] it works fine, but when I deploy to the production server I am receiving the error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages'. I have added references to Syste.Web.WebPages and Syste.Web.WebPages.Deployment but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the reference to copy local so that the dll appears in your bon folder or alternatively use the "add deployable dependencies" function in vs for a better way.

the problem is your production server doesn't have the library in it's gac so you need to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx however it is an MVC project but will work for you.